# What are best practices for update dependencies in Python with Poetry?

Tags: python, dependencies, dependency-management, python-poetry

What is the best practice to automatically update python dependencies when working with `poetry` on `github`?

I would simply set up an action that runs `poetry update` (https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#update) in a new branch and opens a PR.

This method makes `dependabot` and `renovate` unnecessary, and since I'm used to working with those with other programming languages, I want to check whether my intuition about this as a best practice is a good one.

Side note: `poetry` + `dependabot` do not seem to be a good option because of [this issue](https://github.com/dependabot/dependabot-core/issues/4435) for which I haven't found a good solution.

Comment: when you want poetry to update your packages? i.e. what are scenarios for this

Comment: Yes. Update my dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

`poetry update` updates your dependencies within the version range given in your `pyproject.toml`. So effectively it updates your `poetry.lock` file and also installs the updated packages.

Within your Update-CI you probably don't want to install anything. So run `poetry lock` instead.

At the moment, there is no `poetry`command that will also ugrade the version ranges given in your `pyproject.toml`. If you have something like `^1.0.0` as a version range for a dependency, a `poetry update` or `poetry lock` will never give you a `2.0.0` version of this dependency.

I have very good experience with `renovate` [[docs](https://docs.renovatebot.com/)] [[repo](https://github.com/renovatebot/renovate)] [[home](https://www.mend.io/renovate/)] for doing all that update stuff.

Comment: Ok, thank for the heads up. I'll give a try with renovate.